# Remove some characters in vim file

Tags: linux, vim

i am beginner in programming and  see some characters in vim file  like

```
1^I3218610^I173170667^ITCGA-2J-AAB1-10$
```

I tried some commands to remove theses characters but it was not productive.
Can i ask how to remove these characters and make it neat and tidy for alining?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? What do you want exactly? "alining"? Remove which characters?

Comment: Which characters do you want to remove? To get a basic understanding on how to use vim, I recommend the tutorial. You can start it by calling `vimtutor` on the command line.

Comment: i tried :  set invlist and see some characters like ^ and $ at the end of all lines. so i tried to remove them by using                                                                                             %s/\r/\r/g" " 's/\n/\r\n/' "  "%s/^M//g"

Comment: i want to do alignment  after removing these characters

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you have `:set list`. Vim then uses special visible representations for (otherwise hard to differentiate) whitespace elements: a tab shows as `^I`, and the end of the line has `$`. (Actually, that is just the default from the `'listchars'` option.) This is just a special way of rendering your text; the actual text isn't changed! (That's why you cannot get rid of the characters via `:%s`.)

Unless you're currently investigating whitespace issues, just `:set nolist`. This should change your display to something like

```
1       3218610 173170667       TCGA-2J-AAB1-10
```

You can then do further "aligning" by fiddling with the `'tabstop'` value, which affects the spacing between the columns (again, purely for rendering, not modifying the text itself). Any other alignment would have to involve adding / removing spaces or tab characters, physically in the text. For powerful alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)